# What should our chatroom be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site has an official chat room which can be reached by clicking the "Stack Exchange" logo on the upper left corner.

Each site chooses a nickname for its chat room to put some personality into the site.

Please propose a name for the chat room, with one name per answer.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest the following:

What on Earth?

Comment: Haha! Best of all!

Answer (score 6):

**Pangaea**

Here are some more characters so I can post this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see a need for a special name, keep the name "Earth Science".

Answer (score 4):

Rumblings

Has been used to refer to sound heard in the earth as well as the sky. Can also refer to (perhaps discontent) chit-chat.

Answer (score 2):

Gaia, might be a good name given the subject.

Answer (score -4):

Mother Earth's knowledge fairies